# One Line Regex, match all words separated by whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I am trying to create a regEx that can match the entire above line into seperate groups:

Sample Message: `2019-10-07 11:13:19.75   New York   America   INFO   Server is connected. Server Id [34] Address [127.0.0.1:54266]`

EDIT: The groups are separated by multiple whitespace characters at least 2 whitespace characters but usually 3.

EDIT2: The bracketed terms in the message portion may not appear at all, or one may appear without the other or they may appear in a different order.

Group1: `2019-10-07 11:13:19.75`

Group2: `New York`

Group3: `America`

Group4: `INFO`

Group5: `Server is connected. Server Id [34] Address [127.0.0.1:54266]`

Im also trying to select anything inside square brackets ([  ]) and also a special match case for IP addresses. This doesnt have to be included in the same regex though. But would be nice if possible.

Ive been able to match individual groups, but I cant seem to get it all going in 1 line.

Here is what I have so far:

Group1: `/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}/`

Group2: `/(?<=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{2}.*)\S+/`

Group3: `/(?<=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{2}.*\S.\s{3}).?\S+/`

Group4: `/(?<=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{2}(.*\S.\s{3}){2}).?\S+/`

Group5: `/(?<=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{2}(.*\S.\s{3}){3}).*/`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you know the difference between `York America` and `New York`?

Comment: What are the character(s?) between the fields? Multiple space characters, a single tabulation, or something else? If it's multiple space characters, are their amount fixed or does it vary depending on the field's length?

Comment: I'd say you're over-complicating this, all you need to do it split the string on, whatever the dividing character, job done. If you can't do that, the your not going to have any more joy with a regex as you still don't know what the dividing character is. This seems like very poorly formatted data, JSON, or CSV would be a much better choice to send data

Comment: like `string.split(/\s{2,}/)`?

Comment: @Aaron The groups are separated by multiple whitespace characters at least 2 whitespace characters but usually 3. Sorry I forgot to clarify this initially

Comment: Is it reasonable to assume the fields themselves will never contain more than one consecutive spaces? That would make the solution trivial (use ` {2,}` as separator)

Comment: Looks almost like the tsv format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think Liam and Thomas are right, just split by `\s+` and trim the values.**

But I was curious about how to regex this...

Try this monster:
`(?<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s+(?<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{2})\s+(?<city>(?:\S|\s(?!\s))*)\s+(?<country>(?:\S|\s(?!\s))*)\s+(?<level>INFO|WARN|ERROR)\s+(?<message>[^\[]+\[(?<serverid>\d+)\][^\[]+\[(?<serverip>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}:\d{1,5})\])`

here: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vHr9hi/1)

Comment: Wow that's amazing!  Unfortunately I wont be able to use .split for my application. Ill probably end up using your solution even though its a monster :).  I did notice that it doesnt match any groups if there are no bracketed terms in the message section.  These bracketed terms are optional and may not appear at all, or they may appear in a different order or may appear multiple times.

Comment: @Sam Why can't you use split? This reeks of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @3limin4t0r because this is a regex I need to supply to a library.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're over doing it, if you know that your seperator is at least two white spaces, juste `split` by `\s{2,}` :

```js
const message = `2019-10-07 11:13:19.75   New York   America   INFO   Server is connected. Server Id [34] Address [127.0.0.1:54266]`;

const groups = message.split(/\s{2,}/g)
console.log(groups);
```